# Is it possible to pass a struct as a parameter in Go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to pass an array of key, values to another function in Go. Very new to Go so am struggling to figure it out.

```
package main

import(
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/url"
)

type Params struct {
    items []KeyValue
}

type KeyValue struct {
    key string
    value string
}

func main() {
     data := []Params{
          KeyValue{ key: "title", value: "Thingy" },
          KeyValue{ key: "body", value: "Testing 123" }}

     response, error := makePost("test-api.dev", &data)
}

func makePost(urlString string, values []Params) (string, error) {

     v := url.Values{}

    for _, val := range values {
        v.Add(val.key, val.value)
    }

    response, err := http.PostForm(urlString, v)

    defer response.Body.Close()

    contents, err :=  ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    }

    return string(contents), err
}
```

I get errors:

```
val.key undefined (type Params has no field or method key)
val.value undefined (type Params has no field or method key)
```

When I compile however.

Go playground link http://play.golang.org/p/CQw03wZmAV

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean to also iterate over `val.items`?

Comment: You code fragment doesn't compile. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @peterSO apologies, updated.

Comment: @EwanValentine: Why `main.go:21: cannot use KeyValue literal (type KeyValue) as type Params in array element` and `main.go:22: cannot use KeyValue literal (type KeyValue) as type Params in array element`? http://play.golang.org/p/gAaSsBDFGI

Comment: @peterSO that's what I'm trying to find out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you have an `[]Params` but you are trying to initialize with `KeyValue`s.

```
data := []Params{
      KeyValue{ key: "title", value: "Thingy" },
      KeyValue{ key: "body", value: "Testing 123" }}
```

Instead, try:

```
data := &Params{items: []KeyValue{
    {key: "title", value: "Thingy"},
    {key: "body", value: "Testing 123"},
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

`values` is a `[]Params`. When you iterate over it, `val` will be a `Params`, but you're treating it as though it was a `KeyValue`. Did you actually mean to pass an `[]Params` at all, instead of just a `Params` or even just a `[]KeyValue`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks, finally got it working with: http://play.golang.org/p/aCKU5bTnhT

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Params struct {
    items []KeyValue
}

type KeyValue struct {
    key   string
    value string
}

func main() {
    data := Params{items: []KeyValue{
        {key: "title", value: "Thingy"},
        {key: "body", value: "Testing 123"},
    }}

    makePost("test-api.dev", data)
}

func makePost(urlString string, values Params) string {

    for _, val := range values.items {
        fmt.Println("%s", val.key+":"+val.value)
    }

    return string("test")
}
```

Comment: Maybe you just simplified your code, but as @hobbs points out, you really don't need the `Params` struct as all you really care about passing is the `[]KeyValue`.  You could even ditch the whole `Params` `[]KeyValue` as you don't care about ordering and thus all you've really done is create a `map[string]string`